# Using fullpage.js with React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to make a React Component that uses fullpage.js. However, I'm having issues trying to integrate the javascript files from the fullpage.js library. This is what I have (abbreviated):

```
import React from 'react';

let $ = require('jquery')(require('jsdom').jsdom().defaultView);
import 'fullpage.js';

class FullPage extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="fullpage">
        <div className="section">Some section</div>
        <div className="section">Some section</div>
        <div className="section">Some section</div>
        <div className="section">Some section</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

However, using this component gives an error:

```
Error: jQuery requires a window with a document
```

Even if I have defined a window using JSDOM.

Beyond fullpage.js, how should I go about using libraries that require jQuery into React components?

Comment: Did you every figure out how to make this work? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.$ = require('jquery')(window);
```

Could you please try with above code?